# API using Hapi & Async - How to empty array / execute something right after "reply" or at each new "get"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, async.js

I'm building a small API that fetches data and perform tasks on it (using async), stores some of this data in an array using push, and then shows it to a client with Hapi's reply().

I'm looking to empty my array (for example using arrayname.length = 0) right after the server has sent an answer to the client.

Current code follows this logic:

```
let data = []

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/api/{data}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        async.parallel([
            function(callback) {
                  // fetch some data, work with it and then add it to our array using push
                  data.push ({ // example data
                  bla:'blabla', 
                  number:'10' 
                  });
                  callback();
            },
            function(callback) { // another time (...)
                  data.push ({
                  bla:'blabla',
                  number:'2'
                  });
                  callback();
              }
        ],
        function(err) { // This is the final callback, sort data and send it using reply
              data.sort(function (a, b) {
              return a.number - b.number
              })
              reply(data)
              console.log(request.params.data)
        })
    }
});

server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
});
```

With the current code if I refresh my page, data gets added to the already existing data array.

I tried for several hours and find no way to empty this array right after reply(data) has been called.

Is there any way to do that, or would I have to nest my parallel async functions with an async serie and perform the emptying that way? (Haven's been able to succeed either + sounds overkill).

Is there a way to simply execute something once "reply" has been called or when there is a new "get" so that each client can have the only the data generated by it's request and not also the data that was in the array before?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe create the array inside `handler`? Every time you hit the route, it will be initialized as an empty array.  Personally, I do not see any sense in what you are trying to achieve here...

Comment: I have the feeling I tried that and it created a problem, but obviously it doesn't. Very simple, don't know what went on with my troubled mind. Thank you very much for your answer! If post this as an answer I can accept it if you want, @piotrbienias

Answer (score 2):

I'm in agreement with all of the answers suggesting to put the array within the handler.  With the array situated out side of the request handler, all request coming through will be writing to the same array.  Even if you clear this array at the end of your handler logic, it is not guaranteed to be empty for the next request context since you can have many request context in play.

Answer (score 1):

Following @piotrbienias's advice I created the array inside handler rather than at the beginning of my file and it's cleared each time I do a new request on my API, so I don't need to empty it once the reply is sent.

Thanks, @piotrbienias!